# Can we avoid overlapping on e-signature in pdf which is inserted in the container using PDFTron in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdftron

Kindly someone reply. Is there any solution to avoid overlapping of signature in a tag/file

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How will anyone know what code you wrote for your problem?

Comment: Please include sample project, screenshot of what is going wrong so we can better assist you. Thanks. For PDFTron support inquiry, please submit a ticket in the official website: https://www.pdftron.com/support/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.